# Return row label for largest & 2nd largest value in criteria range

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have the following table

| Name | Point | Bonus | Total |  | Pos | 1st | Name | 2nd | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 10 | 8 | 6 |  | Point | 11 |  | 10 |  |
| Sue | 9 | 5 | 3 |  | Bonus | 12 |  | 9 |  |
| Joe | 11 | 2 | 4 |  | Total | 10 |  | 7 |  |
| Susan | 7 | 9 | 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Tim | 1 | 12 | 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Ellie | 9 | 8 | 7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

In `G2` I have the following formula

```
{=LARGE(IF($B$1:$D$1 =$F2, $B:$D),1)}
```

Which returns the largest `Point` value, as `11`.

In `H2` I want to return the name where the `Point` value is `11`. so the value for `H2` should be `Joe`

Then in `J2` want to do the same for the 2nd largest value. So the value of `J2` should be `Bob`

Comment: Depending on your version of Excel, you could use `INDEX(MATCH(...`, `XLOOKUP`, `FILTER` and there are probably other ways. Give one of those a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used following formulas as per attached scheenshot.

```
G2=LARGE(INDEX($B$2:$D$7,,MATCH(F2,$B$1:$D$1,0)),1)
H2=INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(G2,INDEX($B$2:$D$7,,MATCH(F2,$B$1:$D$1,0)),0))
I2=LARGE(INDEX($B$2:$D$7,,MATCH(F2,$B$1:$D$1,0)),2)
J2=INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(I2,INDEX($B$2:$D$7,,MATCH(F2,$B$1:$D$1,0)),0))
```

And if you have Microsoft-365 then could try below formula to get names directly.

```
=LET(x,FILTER($B$2:$D$7,$B$1:$D$1=F2),FILTER($A$2:$A$7,x=LARGE(x,1)))
```

[image]